# What is the best function with a y limit for data processing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm processing a large set of data using numpy and want to take an input between 0 and infinity to output a value between 0 and 1 with greater inputs giving greater outputs and adjustable gradient. I have used `y = arctan(x*S)/1.58` with x as input value and S being the slope between x and y. Is this computationally efficient, or is there a better function or way to do this?

[image: Plot with S=0.2]

Comment: You're looking for an [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), and there are lots of good options, `arctan` being one of them.

Comment: As a side note, you should use `math.pi/2`, not 1.58.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a bijection between the unit interval and the real line. In machine learning, these are often called [activation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function). Arctan is one activation function, although you will have to transform it to get it to go from 0 to 1 (you should divide by pi, not pi/2, and then add 0.5; also, as DYZ says in a comment, use math.pi, not a decimal approximation). [Logistic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) are probably a bit more common. You can also use any probability distribution's CDF.

Comment: Thank you, a logistic function may serve my purpose better and the linked activation function table on Wikipedia is a big help.